# how to pass variables as arguments in two dimensional array in verilog

Tags: arrays, verilog

How to pass variables as arguments array in Verilog because in a 48 bit array? I want an array of 23 bits from the first MSB 1. Can someone say me the method or give program for this condition?

For example, if I give an input like:
001010101010111000100010010100100110001101010101
the output should be:
01010101011100010001001.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to perform slicing of packed array.

There can be many methods for doing this, for example *streaming operators* operators etc.

I've provided a couple of methods [here](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/JRG). Using ***for*** loops and the ***-: operator***. If you are using system-verilog, then the use of -: operator is preferred.

P.S. : I still don't get why did you mention *two dimensional array*.